# jQuery / PHP - How to get random file in folder

Tags: php, jquery

I have my php code as follows:

```
<?php include("/myfolder/my-file-01.html"); ?>
```

and in the folder `myfolder` I have 2 files: `my-file-01.html` and `my-file-02.html`

Now, with jQuery or php, how can I randomly include `my-file-01.html` or `my-file-02.html` in one refresh my website (F5).

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, you could also load them inside an array thru `scandir`, point it into the files path, then use an `array_rand`:

```
$path_to_files = 'path/to/myfolder/';
$files = array_diff(scandir($path_to_files), array('.', '..'));
$file = $files[array_rand($files)];
require "$path_to_files/$file";
```

However, if you have other files other than `my-file` prefix, it'll get mixed up, so to prevent that from happening, you could use a `glob` solution instead. This will only search file/s that has that `my-file` prefix. Example:

```
$files = glob('myfolder/my-file-*.html');
$file = $files[array_rand($files)];
require $file;
```

Answer (score 3):

You generate a random number which is 1 or 2 with the `rand()` function.

```
<?php

//Create random number 1 or 2:
$random = rand(1,2);

//Add zero before 1 or 2
$random = "0".$random;

//Include random file:
include("/myfolder/my-file-".$random.".html");
```

Comment: Dang, I was in the middle of writing the same thing...good solution.